# Vacuum Transitions and Lorentz Symmetry Breaking

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, standard-model, vacuum, symmetry-breaking

There are many "bumblebee" models [1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee_models), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0412320) where Lorentz invariance is violated usually resulting from a local vector or tensor field acquiring a nonzero vacuum expectation value

We do not know whether we are in the true vacuum state or in a "false"/metastable vacuum state that could decay. Even if we were in a true vacuum state, there could be (theoretically speaking) highly energetic events in the universe that would "inject" energy to the vacuum, changing its ground state into an excited/unstable/false vacuum state (this was confirmed by Gian Francesco Giudice, a particle physicist from CERN working in vacuum decay models, who told me this was possible in an email). Then this "new" metastable vacuum could decay into a lower vacuum state or even return to the initial true vacuum state. But then, even if we found that the Standard Model was complete (or that at least it was in a true vacuum state), would these vacuum phase transitions (from the true vacuum into a false one and then decaying) change the particle physics we know (changing the fundamental forces, fields and particles or even replacing them with totally different ones)?

And if that would be possible, then, since physics could change depending on the energy and the characteristics of the vacuum, could one of these vacuum phase transitions result in a specific configuration of particles, forces, fields, symmetries and groups that would be compatible with a vacuum from a Lorentz-symmetry violating theory that are cited in [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0412320) (e.g Holger Nielsen's random dynamics: so in that vacuum one would find no fundamental symmetries in the smallest scales, as Nielsen proposes)?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a "bumblebee" model only refers to one in which a vector (as opposed to a higher-rank tensor) field gains a spontaneous vacuum expectation value.

Comment: @Buzz yes, but that does depend on the vacuum we are considering, doesn't it? I mean, imagine our vacuum did not have any vacuum expectation value (i.e it's zero), but then by some process our vacuum gets excited and turns into a metastable vacuum. Wouldn't it be possible that this new "false vacuum" could have a non-zero vacuum expectation value?

Comment: I was just talking about the meaning of the "bumblebee" terminology.